# Clearing the Clipboard

Tags: c#, console, clipboard

I have the following console application in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PreventScreenshot
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("---Prevent Screenshot from being taken---");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("DLL operation started.  Try to take a screenshot");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Supposedly, the application clears the clipboard every second.  However, it is not working.  What is the problem?

Edit:

I just edited the code.  When I try to run the program, the clipboard is still not cleared.  What is happening?

Comment: This is ill-advised.  The clipboard is used for many other things besides screenshots; you're going to make your users very unhappy.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move `Console.ReadLine()` after `timer1.Start()`

Currently, your application is waiting for an enter press, then starts the timer and exists immediately.

**Regarding your edited post:**

You are using `Timer` from `System.Windows.Forms`, it is not suitable for console applications. Try using timer from `System.Timers`.

Comment: I edited the code (see question).  However it still does not work.

Comment: I tried using System.Timers.  However, it seems that it does not support the Tick method.  Do you have any idea how to go about it?

Comment: Its a different, yet similar class. It has Elapsed event for that.

Comment: @alex Thank you.  I have modified the code again (please see question).  However, I am getting this error: ThreadStateException - Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

Comment: Oh god, please stop changing the original question :) All the answers would look really strange because they would suggest changes that are already there. And put [STAThread] attribute to the main method, as jlew suggested.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. The thing is, this timer executes your handler in a separate thread. That may have caused this issue. You can just drop the timers altogether and go with cycle with Thread.Sleep() in it. Or you can make a winforms application and use timer from winforms.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to setup and start your timer BEFORE the ReadLine() call, otherwise your code will not reach it.
2. Your application threads need to be in Single Threaded Apartment (STA) mode . Apply the [STAThread] attribute to the method.
   See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx

Comment: I edited the code (see question).  However it still does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I edited the code and I think something is working.  However I am getting the following error: ThreadStateException - Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.